# Call window.onload function in code behind not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written a js function in aspx like below

```
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('grid-overlay').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Now I want to call this function in code behind. I tried like below:-

```
 if (dtmkey.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       HidMode.Value = "M";
       HidMKey.Value = dtmkey.Rows[0]["mkey"].ToString();

       var scriptSource = "function onload() { alert(""); };\n";
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "HelpScript", scriptSource, true);  // Not working
   }
```

kindly suggest what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.onload` is an event handler for the `load` event of a `window` & the attached `function` is `function` that will be called on `load` event.

Also it is not clear what you are trying to do at this point

```
// I ran this variable in console, it threw unexpected syntax
var scriptSource = "function onload() { alert(""); };\n"; //
```

Are you trying to call a function expression here?
you can make this changes and test it

```
function onload(){  // This is a function expression and onload not same as window.onload
        document.getElementById('grid-overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

window.onload = function () {
        onload() // call onload function here once window has finished loading
    }
```

If you are looking for `onload` here you can replace the below snippet

```
var scriptSource = "function onload() { alert(""); };\n"; with `onload();`
```

Comment: what is `with onload();` ?? i didnt get that

Comment: if you are looking this part to get executed document.getElementById('grid-overlay').style.display = 'block'; then there you can call onload function

Comment: is this is fine ? `var scriptSource = "onload();";
           ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "HelpScript", scriptSource, true);`

Comment: i tried ur code, getting error as `Out of stack space error` at `onload()`

Comment: I think that is not a fine since 
var scriptSource = "onload();" this will result it unexpected syntax;
instead you can just write onload(); it is actually calling onload function that we defined

Comment: can u update the answer, i m getting bit confused with the syntax

Comment: are you using ie can you please check it in other browsers?

Comment: I tried like this on CHROME `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "HelpScript", "onload()", true); ` but it is not working either in chrome too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105759/discussion-between-user2181397-and-coder).